# Como enviar somente a quantidade dos produtos que foram selecionados no checkbox?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Exibi uma tabela de itens e nessa tabela adicionei um checkbox para cada item e um campo para pegar as quantidades de cada item.

Estou conseguindo enviar para o PHP somente os itens marcados no checkbox (era o que eu queria).

Porém não consigo fazer o mesmo com a quantidade, pois estou enviando via POST a quantidade de todos os itens da tabela, tanto os itens que foram selecionados como os que não foram.

Quero enviar a quantidade somente dos itens selecionados, ou quem sabe continuar enviando assim como esta e depois arrumar o array la no PHP eliminando as quantidades vazias.

Como eu poderia resolver isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poderia criar uma funcao js pra ir adicionando numa variavel hiddden o id e o valor

Comment: Cadê o código??

Comment: Remove valores nulos de forma rápida  `$arrayLimpo = array_filter($_POST['cantidad']);`

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de usar o foreach, você usaria um for com um contador `$i` que seria incrementado de 1. Esse valor de `$i` iria para o value do seu checkbox. Assim você teria a posição dele em sua tabela.

Adicionaria um input hidden para cada linha na tabela que guardaria a informação `$item['id']`.

Assim, você teria os índices que foram preenchidas no vetor $cantidad, conseguindo recuperar a quantidade dos produtos e no input hidden os id dos produtos.

Não sei se essa é a melhor solução, mas foi a que veio a minha cabeça no momento.